# Which files "git checkout" modifies?

Tags: git

I was on `feature` branch, and wanted to checkout to `develop`.

Relative to `develop` branch, in my `feature` branch file "D1" was modified.

Relative to `develop` branch, in my working tree file "M" was modified, "D1" and "D2" were deleted.

Relative to `feature` branch, my working tree of course had files "D1" and "D2" deleted, and "M" modified. Nothing was staged.

When I ran `git checkout develop`, git added back file "D1" to the working tree, but did nothing about "D2" and "M". Why did git treat "D1" and "D2" differently? And why didn't it complain about "M" being modified - even though it's not committed yet?

I tried to follow the explanation in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/git-checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current) about which files `git checkout new_branch` can safely modify. But it wasn't enough to understand this outcome.

Edit (answer to @torek comment):

Initially, I'm on `feature`.
`git status --short` says (I put file names in quotes to make it obvious):

```
D "D1"
D "D2"
M "M"
```

.gitignore is empty.

`git diff --name-status feature develop` says:

```
M "D1"
```

`git rev-parse` commands only yield commit IDs.

Comment: You're initially on `feature`, correct? And (initially, before any checkout commands) `git status --short` prints nothing? Also of interest: what are the contents of `.gitignore` before and after each `git checkout` step? For concreteness, you might want to run `git rev-parse feature` and `git rev-parse develop` and also `git diff --name-status feature develop` (this will help identify precisely which files `git checkout` must touch: I think you have done this above but this way we'll have machine-readable output).

Comment: @torek see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The setup

We don't have raw commit IDs here, but we don't need them.  We also can't draw much of a commit graph, but we don't really need it either.  But, just for concreteness of a sort, I'll draw in some pretend ones, just so that there are things to refer to and we don't have to write out the names `feature` and `develop` all the time.

What we do have is two different commits (which are part of a commit graph), an index, and a work-tree.  We're on branch `feature` initially as well.

#### Some definite things about the two commits

Let's draw the commits first:

```
...--A--B--...--D     <-- develop
         \
          C--...--F   <-- HEAD -> feature
```

Commit `D` is the tip of branch `develop` and commit `F` is the tip of branch feature.  Since we're on branch `feature`, the file `.git/HEAD` contains the name `feature`, which is how Git knows to work with/on branch `feature`.

Commit `D` contains a bunch of files, including at least file `D1`.  It's not immediately obvious from all of the above output whether commit `D` contains file `D2` and `M`.  (It's usually best to show exact output from each command, in case there's something subtle going on here.)  But, running `git status --short` is supposed to have printed this:

```
D "D1"
D "D2"
M "M"
```

This isn't quite right.  (Here's some actual output from a different `git status --short`:

```
$ git status --short
 M pytest/p9conn.py
?? backend/backend.h+
```

Note the leading space in front of `pytest/p9conn.py`, above the first `?` on the next line: this indicates that the `M` in the output is telling us that the modification is between the index and work-tree, rather than the current commit and the index.)  I'm going to assume that instead, it printed:

```
 D D1
 D D2
 M M
```

which includes a leading space in front of each `D`.  *That* means that files `D1` and `D2` have specifically been removed, but not `git rm`-ed.

(Perhaps the actual output was instead:

```
D  D1
D  D2
M  M
```

Note the two spaces between each letter-code and the file names.  In this case, the two `D` files *have* been `git rm`-ed, and file `M` is `git add`-ed.  But you said "nothing was staged" so I'm assuming one space, then the letter-code, then one more space, then the file names.)

#### The index/staging-area and work-tree

If nothing was staged, the index (or staging area) must necessarily match the current commit (which, remember, is `F`: `HEAD` points to branch-name `feature` and branch-name `feature` points to commit `F`).  Since `git status --short` had spaces before each letter-code, this also tells us that the index has the same entries as the `HEAD` commit, i.e., that nothing is yet staged for a new commit.

But we did see two `D` (deleted) files: `D1` and `D2` are both showing as deleted from the *work-tree*.  To be deleted from the work-tree, they must be in the index.  That means files `D1` and `D2` are *both* in the index right now—and as we just noted, the index matches the `HEAD` commit.  Likewise, we saw one `M` file.  To be modified, file `M` *must* be in the index, and hence in commit `F`.  This tells us more things for certain about the current `HEAD` commit `F`.  Let's write them in.

#### More definite things about the two commits

We now know for certain that files `D1`, `D2`, and `M` are all three in commit `F`.  *And*, we ran:

```
$ git diff --name-status feature develop
M "D1"
```

This tells us that files `D1`, `D2`, and `M` are *also* in commit `D`!

Obviously file `D1` is in both commit `D` on `develop` and commit `F` on `feature`, because it's *different* between the two branch-tips.

But now we *also* know that file `D2` is in both commits *and* is *identical* in both commits.  We know this because we proved, from the `git status` output, that `D2` is in commit `F`.  If `D2` were not in commit `D`, we'd see it as *deleted* when seeing how to change from commit `F` to commit `D`.  We don't see that, so it must not be deleted.  Moreover, it must be *the same* in both commits: if it were different, we'd see it as *modified* when seeing how to change from `F` to `D`.

The same goes for file `M`.  We don't see it in the `git diff --name-status` output, so it must exist in commit `D` at the tip of `develop`, and it must be the same there as it is here in `feature`.

## The `git checkout`

> When I ran git checkout develop, git added back file "D1" to the working tree, but did nothing about "D2" and "M". Why did git treat "D1" and "D2" differently?

The way `git checkout develop` (which needs to switch the work-tree contents to some extent, to try to match commit `D`) does its job begins with comparing the current *index* to the target commit.

We know that the current index has files `D1`, `D2`, and `M` in it.  We also know that the version of `D1` in the index matches that of commit `F` and therefore *differs* from the version of `D1` in commit `D`.

This means that for `git checkout develop` to succeed, it will have to extract the version of file `D1` from commit `D`, to the index, and hence on to the work-tree.  That won't clobber any existing file, as the work-tree version of `D1` is just gone.  Git puts that operation in a queue of "work to do" before actually doing it, then goes on to look for more work, since it needs to make sure that the whole checkout is OK, then do everything all at once, or else stop and do nothing.

What *else* does Git need to change in the index?  Well, it looks over the index contents for file `D2`, but that's the *same* in `F` and `D`, so to switch from `F` to `D`, there's nothing to do.  It also looks over the index contents for file `M`, but again, that's the *same* in both `F` and `D`: there's nothing to do there.

(It also must compare any and all additional files in commit `D` and/or in the current index, but those all match as well.)

So, having now determined that no files will be clobbered, Git goes back to the work-queue, which says "extract file `D1` from commit `D` into the index and the work-tree".  It does that, then updates `.git/HEAD` to refer to `develop` (which then points to commit `D`), and the checkout is complete.

> And why didn't it complain about "M" being modified - even though it's not committed yet?

It probably should, in some theoretical sense, and some versions of Git seem to do that in at least some cases.  However, as we saw, the index version of `M` matches in both `F` and `D`, so `git checkout` does not have to change `M` at all.  Your particular version of Git not only doesn't bother changing `M`, it does not even bother looking at it, to see that `M` is modified.  So it doesn't print `M M`.

Anyway, that's the answer: `git checkout` finds the *minimum amount of work it can do*.  Since commits `D` and `F` differ only in the contents of file `D1`, that's the minimum work: change the contents of `D1` as stored in the index and work-tree.

Sometimes there's more work: besides changing file contents, sometimes `git checkout` must *create* a file (that in the `--name-status` diff from "current commit" to "proposed checkout", shows as `A`dded).  Sometimes `git checkout` must *remove* a file (that in the diff from "current commit" to "proposed checkout", shows as `D`eleted).  And of course, it's possible that instead of simply not existing, these files might exist in the work-tree (whether or not they're in the index) with contents that *don't match* one or both commits.  In these cases Git has to be extra-careful with work-tree contents.  (This is when `.gitignore` starts to matter: if a file is listed in `.gitignore`, Git feels free to clobber it!)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm using your answer to understand git better! (And of course, you're right I forgot to put an extra space in front of the output of `git  status --short`)